# Add an "All" option to PrimeNG Dropdown

Tags: angular, primeng-dropdowns, p-dropdown

I'm trying to display data based on value selected in a dropdown. I need help adding an "All" option to the PrimeNG dropdown. The dropdown takes data from a json array of objects, and displays data corresponding to the object selected.

*teams.json*

```
teams: Team[] = [
{tenant: "ABC", apps:[1, 2, 3]},
{tenant: "XYZ", apps:[1, 3, 5]},
{tenant: "UVW", apps:[2, 4, 5]}
]
```

```
<p-dropdown [options]="teams" [(ngModel)]="selectedTeam" optionLabel="tenant" (ngModelChange)="onSelectChange($event)"> </p-dropdown>
```

So when I click ABC on the dropdown, I'm able to show the apps ABC uses and so on. When I click "All", it should show me all tenant names and apps used by each of them.

Using `<select>` this seems easy to do, I can just add an option like this:

`<option value="all">All</option>`

How do I achieve the same using p-dropdown?

I could add an object to the array with the structure `{ tenant: 'All', ... }`  but that is obviously not right. Please help!